# is there any way to combine overlapping time period from datetime dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have 2 dataframes each having two columns indicating the starting and ending of different events in a particular day. the condition is that there will an overlap in the time period across different data frames but no overlap of events will occur in the same data frame.

A new table must be created and if there is any overlap occurring between dataframeA and dataframeB, I need to combine the events such that only the earliest start and last end is present. Also the not overlapping time periods also needs to be present.

e.g.:
Dataframe_A

| Startime | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-20 12:04:48 | 2021-06-20 12:20:37 |
| 2021-06-20 13:04:49 | 2021-06-20 13:08:38 |
| 2021-06-20 13:10:10 | 2021-06-20 13:38:39 |
| 2021-06-20 14:10:34 | 2021-06-20 14:28:40 |
| 2021-06-20 15:06:25 | 2021-06-20 15:24:41 |

Dataframe_B

| Startime | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-20 12:07:48 | 2021-06-20 12:27:37 |
| 2021-06-20 13:14:49 | 2021-06-20 13:38:38 |
| 2021-06-20 13:40:10 | 2021-06-20 13:58:39 |
| 2021-06-20 14:22:34 | 2021-06-20 14:47:40 |
| 2021-06-20 15:44:25 | 2021-06-20 15:54:41 |

Expected dataframe;

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-20 12:04:48 | 2021-06-20 12:27:37 |
| 2021-06-20 13:04:49 | 2021-06-20 13:38:38 |
| 2021-06-20 13:40:10 | 2021-06-20 13:58:39 |
| 2021-06-20 14:10:34 | 2021-06-20 14:47:40 |
| 2021-06-20 15:06:25 | 2021-06-20 15:24:41 |
| 2021-06-20 15:44:25 | 2021-06-20 15:54:41 |

Comment: the last row in dataframe B is incorrect : start time can not be greater than end time

Comment: thanks, i have corrected it. do you know any ways in which i can solve this ?

Comment: kindly explain the logic; line 2 of the expected output does not seem right; the second line of dataframe A does not overlap with the second line from dataframe B.